# Automatic routing in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have a website in symfony2. Now I am create a controller and action like this

```
class FriendController extends Controller { 

  public function indexAction()
     {

         return $this->render('xxxxBundle:Default:index.html.twig');

     } 
}
```

after that create route in routing.yml file

```
name:
    pattern:  /index
    defaults: { _controller: xxxxBundle:Friend:index }
```

My need is automatically create routes while creating controller and action without specifying in routing.yml . Is this possible in Symfony2?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use annotations if you don't want to create a routing.yml file.

Take a look at the documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html